# Proper way to mutate array in vue 3 composition api

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I have a component that receives data from an emit function and I wish to push object's onto an array. The trouble is when I push object onto array the object is empty?? Here is the code :

```
<script setup>
   let formDataHistory = ref([]);

   // Method to be called when there is an emiterUIUpdate event emiited
// from form-modal.vue @param(data) is the form data sent from the
// form submission via the event bus. We will then send this data back
// down to child display-scrap component via a prop.
const updateUI = (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  formDataHistory.value.push(data);
  console.log(formDataHistory);
};
</script>
```

And a snapshot in devtools after pushing item onto array:

[image]

formdataHistory's first element is an empty object after the push action. Any help on proper way to mutate an array is most welcome.

Comment: The logs at the end are XHR requests, and not the one you log in the code. It seems you emit an empty object, maybe also show us that part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Always use const on reactive variables: `const formDataHistory = ref([]);`. The reference itself should never change, only the value.
2. Try `formDataHistory.value = [...formDataHistory.value, data];`. It might be that refs only update if the content is replaced instead of mutated.